# Get fully qualified class name from unqualified class name

Tags: php, namespaces

How can I make this work?

```php
<?php
namespace Target {
  
  class FooBar {
  
  }
}

namespace Test {
  
  use Target\FooBar;

  $class = 'FooBar';

  var_dump(new \ReflectionClass(new $class));

}
```

At the moment it fails because Reflection class only finds classes with the full namespace. How can I change this so that it will pickup the class from the use statements? If there a function I'm missing. Trying things like `$class::class` also just makes an error.

My full purpose is to be able to work with annotations for arrays like so:

```php
<?php
namespace Target {
  use Foo\Bar;
  
  class FooBar {
    /**
     * @var Bar[]|null
     */
    public ?array $foo;
  }
}
```

Maybe what I'm doing is impossible and I should just have the fully qualified class name in the annotations.

I'm working with PHP7.4

Comment: `$class = FooBar::class` should work paired with `new \ReflectionClass(new $class)`. Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: The `use` statements are syntactic shortcuts. In the compiled code they do not exist and the class names are fully qualified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible. According to [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php) a fully qualified class name should be used in a dynamic class name.

> One must use the fully qualified name (class name with namespace prefix). Note that because there is no difference between a qualified and a fully qualified Name inside a dynamic class name, function name, or constant name, the leading backslash is not necessary.

```
<?php

namespace Target {
    class FooBar
    {
    }
}

namespace Test {
    $class = 'Target\FooBar';

    var_dump(new \ReflectionClass(new $class));
}
```

As an alternative, there is an option to parse use statements and grab fully qualified class name from there, this way is a bit hacky though.
[github.com/Kdyby/ParseUseStatements](https://github.com/Kdyby/ParseUseStatements)

Comment: I have found it's since possible but only by using a further bit of code to parse the use statements of the original file like this library does https://github.com/Kdyby/ParseUseStatements

Comment: Oh, apparently it's possible, yes. But it's a very very hacky way. Of course it's an option if it's not possible to avoid it. Thanks for the update.